# Fragment already added: GalleryFragment{ef2fd8d #6 id=0x7f090081

Tags: kotlin

I am implementing a search in my app it arrives listing and running the listing but I get error when I click several times to open the search.

code

```
   fun sPesquisa(){

            if (!galleryFragment.isAdded()){
                var mFragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_content,galleryFragment,"Fragment_One");
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }

         val sPesquisa = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.sPesquisa)
        sPesquisa.setOnClickListener {
            sPesquisa()
        }
```

---

error

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: GalleryFragment{ef2fd8d #6 id=0x7f090081 Fragment_One}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1893)
```

full error log->

https://pastebin.com/mP24Yw9B

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, as it is improper to add SOLVED to your title. If you've found a solution, you have three options. 1) Write an answer in the space below to share the solution with future readers who have the same problem. 2) Leave the question as is and wait to see if someone else provides an answer for you. 3) Delete the question using the link provided below the tags. For more information about how this site works, spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages. It will be beneficial to you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution add .addToBackStack(null)

```
  fun sPesquisa(){

            if (!galleryFragment.isAdded()){
                var mFragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_content,galleryFragment,"Fragment_One");
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
```